# How to get blog post and categories from a many-to-many relational database in a single query? Or shoud I?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a database for my blog. It contains three tables, one for the posts, one for the categories, and one for the many-to-many relations between posts and categories:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `pid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`),
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `cid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post_to_category_relation` (
  `pid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`,`cid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `secondary` (`cid`,`pid`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`pid`) REFERENCES `posts` (`pid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`cid`) REFERENCES `categories` (`cid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now I want to query this database, retrieve the information for one post, and display this post on the web, using PHP.

But I'm unsure how to do this.

All the information for a single post is in the `posts` table: the post title, the post text, the post author, the publication date, and the URL slug. So I can build my page with one query.

Except, that table does not contain the categories.

Originally, I wanted to save the categories as a string (e.g. "apples,oranges,bananas") and `explode(",", ...)` that string to create the links to the category pages. This would have allowed me to create the whole post page with one database query. But now ...

**Do I really have to do a second query to retrieve the categories to the post?** Or is there a way to get all I need in one query – maybe something that gives me a multidimensional array (or an object) with a structure similar to this:

```
Array
(
    [pid] => 1
    [post] => "Hello, World!"
    ...
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => apples
            [1] => bananas
        )
)
```

How is this commonly done? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecad8/12

```
select posts.pid, group_concat(categories.category)
from posts

left outer join post_to_category_relation as ptcr
on ptcr.pid = posts.pid

left outer join  categories
on categories.cid = ptcr.cid

where posts.pid = 1
```

Then, in your application, you can `explode()` the categories column into an array with `,` as the delimiter.